# c++ error: request for member 'view' in

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm working on a bit of code for my C++ class, and I'm stuck.

I'm actually using Polymorphism dynamic binding, I have successfully store the objects into my vector and now I would like to display all the objects that are being stored in the vector ShapeTwoD.

Here's the bit of the assignment I'm working on:

Shape2DLin.cpp

```
void Shape2DLink::Display()
{
    vector<ShapeTwoD*>::iterator vectorIt = shapeobject.begin();
    while(vectorIt != shapeobject.end())
    {
        *vectorIt->view();
        vectorIt++;
    }
}
```

SquareImp.cpp

```
void Square::view() const
{
    cout << "Area is: " << area << endl;
}
```

ShapeTwoDImp.cpp

```
void Square::view() const
{
    cout << "Area is: " << area << endl;
}
```

whenever i compile the application I would get the following error. just wonder why is it so?

```
D:\School\CSCI204-C++\Assignment\Assign 2\Assign2>g++ -o test Shape2Dmain.cpp Sh
ape2DLink.cpp ShapeTwoDImp.cpp SquareImp.cpp RectangleImp.cpp CrossImp.cpp
Shape2DLink.cpp: In member function 'void Shape2DLink::Display()':
Shape2DLink.cpp:94:14: error: request for member 'view' in '* vectorIt.__gnu_cxx
::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator-> [with _Iterator = ShapeTw
oD**, _Container = std::vector<ShapeTwoD*>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterat
or, _Container>::pointer = ShapeTwoD**]()', which is of non-class type 'ShapeTwo
D*'
```

Comment: I assume you didn't try `(*vectorIt)->view()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `*vectorIt->view()` use `(*vectorIt)->view()`.
Because the `operator ->` has higher precedence than the dereference/indirection `operator *`.

Comment: thanks alot!! it compiles and work.. but may I know the reason why do i have to bracket the *vectorIt?